# Adding NSOperation to NSOperationQueue that starts asynchronous ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, asihttprequest, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

So I'm trying to do all my REST calls that download data on the background thread so that the UI stays responsive.

I have a viewcontroller that contains a NSOperationQueue. I create an instance of my importer class that is a subclass of NSOperation. Inside the main() method of my importer, I am setting up a ASIHTTPDataRequest. I create the request, then its time to kick off the request.

Problem:
I ran into a problem when starting the request by calling "startAsynchronous" on the request. The delegate call backs never get called. Its like the request starts, downloads its data, but never calls the delegate callback methods.

My solution:
Everything seems to work fine (i.e. callbacks, etc) when I start the request synchronously. Is this the correct solution?

Why does the synchronous call work, but not the asynchronous? I'm modeling my importer class after Apples "TopSongs" sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the method `main()` is end executing, `NSOperation`  seted to finished and released, so you newer receive delegate callbacks because delegate is released.

Comment: Outside of me using ASIHTTPRequest instead of NSURLConnection, the "TopSongs" samples does the same thing I am. It uses [[NSURLConnceciton alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; which is asynchronous as well, and it works fine. So it would seem to me that its something to do with ASIHTTPReqeust's startAsynchronous call.

Comment: did you use code like this:
        do {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        } while (!done);

Comment: yes. I suspect something inside ASIHTTPRequest that is causing this issue. Debugging the asynchronous test I find that it never reaches the line after the "do...while" loop you listed above. Its like the code falling through the do/while statement and never executing any code below that.

Comment: Moving discussion to http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/dc4aab8463fbe0e1/056868cdbf67394c#056868cdbf67394c

Answer (score 6):

ASIHTTPRequest itself should not block the UI if you run it from the main thread.

- ASIHTTPRequest isn't designed to be run from a background thread. [[ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished]](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.m#L1666) calls the "finished" callback on the main thread; it'll never be received by the background thread, so the background thread's run loop never runs.
- ASIHTTPRequest is an NSOperation *anyway*. This is an implementation detail.
- ASIHTTPRequest runs its network code in a background thread by default, so you're unlikely to see much benefit by sticking it in another thread.

If it's parsing the data that's taking a long time, stick that in an operation.

Comment: The main reason I moved the REST request call to my own NSOperation is because after the request is done, it will parse and saving into Core Data on that same background thread, keeping the UI responsive and allowing core data to be notified on the main thread its been updated and therefore updating my table on the main thread.

Comment: So stick the parsing/saving into another thread, and coordinate stuff in the main thread.

Comment: I think I'm getting stung by this currently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274236/why-is-nstimer-blocked-while-another-thread-is-running). I don't get the reasoning for having completion handlers running on the main thread and not the same thread that started them. Often you need to process the downloaded data in the completion handler, but this approach makes that impossible (unless you spawn a new thread from the completion handler).

Comment: @Martin: ASIHTTPRequest is designed to be used from the main thread, perform the request "asynchronously", and then return the response on the main thread; this is the easiest way to prevent concurrency issues. (IIRC, ASIHTTPRequest also performs most/all of its processing on the main thread by default, which is probably not that much more expensive than a context switch.) The canonical way of performing multiple dependent operations is by using dependent NSOperations. ASIHTTPRequest uses NSOperation internally, so you might even be able to do this without too much hassle.