# Why is NSTimer blocked while another thread is running?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, nstimer, asihttprequest

I'm trying to run a lenghty task in the background on the iPhone. I start it with `performSelectorInBackground`. I also create a `NSTimer` on the main thread just to check if things are working. I expected that the timer would run while the other thread does it's thing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
                   selector:@selector(onTimerEvent:)
                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];   

   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(lengthyMethod) withObject:nil];

    NSLog(@"Here we go!");
}

- (void)onTimerEvent:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"timer!");
}
```

The `lenghtyMethod` performs lots of stuff, including URL downloads using **ASIHTTPRequest** etc.

The output from `NSLog` looks like this:

```
2011-03-11 15:17:07.470 MyApp[6613:207] Here we go!    
2011-03-11 15:17:07.570 MyApp[6613:207] timer!
2011-03-11 15:17:07.670 MyApp[6613:207] timer!

// ... several seconds of output from lenghtyMethod omitted ...

2011-03-11 15:17:11.075 MyApp[6613:207] timer!
2011-03-11 15:17:11.170 MyApp[6613:207] timer!
// ... etc ... timer runs as expected when the call is completed ...
```

The problem is that **the background thread seems to block the timer**. My understanding of this was that performSelectorInBackground should run in a new thread separate from the main loop.

I don't get this. While the thread is running I get no output from the timer. Once the call is complete, the timer starts logging again.

For the record, the thread is mostly doing I/O (loading URLs) so there should be ample time for the OS to switch threads. This happens both in the simulator and on the actual device.

Comment: Make sure lengthyMethod doesn't make any calls to the UI and check that you are using ASIHTTPRequest's async methods.

Comment: @Johny Grass: ASIHTTPRequest is async indeed. But does that matter, its already running in the background thread.

Comment: I bet there is something going on with `ASIHTTPRequest`s completion handlers. It seems they are blocking the timer. Huh? Weird.

Comment: (Didn't see your comment before posting my answer) Yes you need to subclass ASIHTTPRequest because the default callbacks are run on the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use):

> For more complex situations, or where you want to parse the response in the background, create a minimal subclass of ASIHTTPRequest for each type of request, and override   requestFinished: and failWithProblem:.

Otherwise if you use the default callbacks, they will be run on the main thread.

Comment: Yes this was indeed the problem. Completely unexpected but at least documented.

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer run on the same thread.
It call the event method on the main thread.

Your lengthyMethod method probably use the main tread to do some operations.
There was 2 ticks before this main thread block.
Check it !

Comment: Note that I am starting lenghtyMethod using `performSelectorInBackground`. So what you are saying is that performSelectorInBackground doesn't cause the method to run in the background? That makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I have not notice this ! I want to read to fast... But why theez was 2 timer ticks before the long treatment ?

Comment: I think I'm starting to get to the root if it:  looks like the callback ("requestComplete:") from ASIHTTPRequest *always* runs on the main thread even though the request itself runs on another thread. Unexpected behavior.